# Adding conditional control to function argument

Tags: conditionals

How do we add conditional control to function arguments?

```el
  (defun f (x)
    (let (x)
      (if (eq (x (or 1 2)))
      (print x)
    (print "Hey!"))))
```

I would like to call:

```el
(f 1)
; 1
(f 2)
; 2
(f 3)
; Hey!
```

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/eintr/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a bunch of things wrong with your code as is:

- `eq` compares two Lisp objects by their identity.  This happens to work with integers due to implementation details, but is not guaranteed to work with numbers in general. 
  For example only `(= 1 1.0)` works as intended, all other comparisons will fail.  Use `=` for that reason (except when comparing floats, then you should be comparing their difference against an appropriate threshold).
- The function is passed `x` as argument, then a local variable `x` is introduced with `nil` for its value, shadowing the function argument.  There is no way the comparison will ever work with that going on.
- The syntax of the predicate doesn't make terribly much sense.  You're passing the `eq` a single argument (it expects two, it's a comparison function after all).  That argument is the result of calling `x` as a function which will fail (there's no such function because it's been bound in a separate namespace only).  Even if it would work, `x` is passed `(or 1 2)` which will evaluate to 1 as that's the first truthy value.

I guess you meant to write this instead:

```
(defun f (x)
  (if (or (= x 1) (= x 2))
      (print x)
    (print "Hey!")))
```

The predicate passed to `if` is `(or ... ...)`, where each argument is the result of comparing `x` to the number you're interested in.  An alternative way of writing this would be the `member` function which searches a list for the first matching item, using `equal` for comparison (which happens to behave almost like `=` for integers):

```
(defun f (x)
  (if (member x '(1 2))
      (print x)
    (print "Hey!")))
```